# Binding two data.table with different length

Tags: r, list, data.table, rbind, cbind

I have a data.table that has structure like

```
library(data.table) #load package
a <- as.data.table(matrix(1,10,10))
b <- as.data.table(matrix(2,2,2))
```

As you can see, they have different dimension.
I want to put together those two data.table.
The result should be, 
first ten rows / first ten columns is "a"
11th and 12th row / 1st and 2nd column is "b"

The reason I need this is because I have a dataset(a) and a foot note(b).
I would like to merge this and export it as a xlsx file. So that under the dataset lies the footnote.

I tried doing this by rbind cbind but this asks me to match the length and if i do, "b" is repeated 5 times each to match the length with "a".

Comment: its class is a data.table. You can think of it as a data.frame.

Comment: Just: `rbindlist(list(a,b), fill = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> y <- as.data.table(matrix(1,10,10))

> u <- as.data.table(matrix(2,2,2))

> merge(y, u, all = TRUE)

    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
 1:  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
 2:  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
 3:  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
 4:  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
 5:  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
 6:  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
 7:  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
 8:  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
 9:  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
10:  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
11:  2  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
12:  2  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
```

Comment: Is there any way I can remove NA or substituting with " " so that it is not seen when exported to an xlsx file, not by subsetting and inserting  " "?

Comment: @kim1298 
 df[is.na(df)] <- 0

Comment: @kim1298 you may want to specify what to be filled for NAs when you write table. That would be a better solution as it will not change the type of variables. For example, `write.csv(df.name, file = "output.csv", na = "")`

Comment: doesn't work if you have duplicate column names

Answer (score 0):

Go with `plyr` package:

```
library(plyr)
l1<-list(a,b)
ldply(l1,data.table)
```

resulting in:

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
2   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
3   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
4   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
5   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
6   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
7   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
8   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
9   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
10  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
11  2  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
12  2  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
```

Comment: Is there any way I can remove NA or substituting with " " so that it is not seen when exported to an xlsx file, not by subsetting and inserting " "?

Comment: apply(plyr::ldply(l1,data.table),2,function(x)ifelse(is.na(x),"",x))